# Execute code at 11:59 PM each day but not on start up

Tags: android, kotlin

Context:

I have this block of code which saves the step count to the database every hour

```
val saveStepsTimer = Timer()
        val saveTask: TimerTask = object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                val stepCount = binding.textViewSteps.text.toString().toInt()
                val dateCurrent = binding.textViewDate.text.toString()
                val steps = Steps(0, stepCount, dateCurrent)
                db.dateCheck(steps, dateCurrent, db.writableDatabase)
                //Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Step Count Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.d(TAG, "Step Count Saved to DB")
            }
        }
        // repeat every hour
        saveStepsTimer.schedule(saveTask, 0L, 1000 * 60 * 60)
```

So I wanted to implement the same type of thing for resetting the step counts daily. I previously had a button for this for testing purposes and before that I tried `System.currentTimeMillis()` which only returned the time at startup and did not dynamically update. That is why I wanted to instead use  `Timer()` to just have it run every 24 hours. However, it also runs every time on startup which is not good.

The reset steps code block:

```
val resetStepsTimer = Timer()
        val resetTask: TimerTask = object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                previousTotalSteps = totalSteps
                binding.textViewSteps.text = 0.toString()
                saveData()
                Log.d(TAG, "Steps Reset")
            }
        }
        // repeat every 24 hrs
        resetStepsTimer.schedule(resetTask, 0L, 1000*60*60*24)
```

The functionality works perfectly, I just don't want it to work randomly when opening the app. I want it to be at 11:59 PM each day.

I tried taking it out of the onCreate function but then the `resetStepsTimer.schedule(resetTask, 0L, 1000*60*60*24)` presents a member declaration error would not work anyway without access to some of the variables (such as `textViewSteps`)

I have also tried:

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val resetIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        // Set the alarm for today at 23:59
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59)

        val alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmManager[AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis()] = resetIntent
```

but with this, I think I need to use another activity in the intent and I'm trying to keep this functionality all in the same activity, unless there is some way to use the AlarmManager in this MainActivity?